# What are some options for server event in a Java app?

Tags: java-8, push-notification, server-sent-events

So ... I have a Java (mobile) client app which has to make a web request (say asynchronously) and say show a waiting for confirmation screen that it will get out of when the server sends a SMS/email to the user and the user clicks/confirms. The client should be make the request and wait/block but listen to say a push notification sorts from the server that the user clicked/confirmed.

What are some options available such that the server can call back or notify the client that the user has clicked / confirmed and the client app can get out of the waiting screen.

Some options that I found during my research:

- Web Sockets - Since the client app is not HTML5/JS, I figure this is not a solution for my problem.
- SSE - From what I read, this seems to be HTML5/JS related but there were mentions of Java although I couldn't find any sample code. It would be helpful if you point to sample or working implementation for SSE (client and server side)
- HTTP2 (generally speaking) Again ... all words and no code!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What so you meant by java? is it android native app?

Comment: Yes, Android native app, at least for this discussion.